# Exporting CSV in powershell to include the "$server" from a read-host entry

Tags: powershell

I wrote a powershell script to get a list of all installed software and version information for each of our servers.  I'd like to be able to export it to a .csv file and name it after the $server name that was entered.

```
Export-CSV -path "C:\Scripts\Server_Audit\$server_Software_List.csv"
```

When I find that file in the folder, it just says .csv.

Do I need to declare that in another fashion so that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An underscore is a valid part of a variable name, so it's trying to add `$server_Software_List` to the file path. One solution is to use `$()` in your string:

```
Export-CSV -path "C:\Scripts\Server_Audit\$($server)_Software_List.csv"
```

Comment: +1 .You can also surround the variable with braces `_${variable}_` `"C:\Scripts\Server_Audit\${server}_Software_List.csv" `